# Cannot access field in Big Query with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>>

Tags: sql, nested, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query using Standard SQL Dialect (ie not Legacy SQL) on BigQuery. My query is:

```
SELECT
date, hits.referer
FROM `refresh.ga_sessions_xxxxxx*`
LIMIT 1000
```

But keep getting the error

```
Error: Cannot access field referer on a value with type 
ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [2:12]
```

Anyone know the proper syntax?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

if you are looking for all referers - try

```
SELECT date, h.referer
FROM `refresh.ga_sessions_xxxxxx*`, UNNEST(hits) as h
```

Comment: I am getting this `Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNNEST` when I am  using the function `UNNEST`.  I am running the query in Standard SQL Dialect only

Comment: Ok I found the mistake, I was using `UNNEST` in the select, it can be used only with `FROM`.

Comment: For those coming here trying to work on firebase here's a nice blogpost: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/bigquery-tip-unnest-function.html

Comment: `UNNEST`: `UNNEST` takes an ARRAY and returns a table with a single row for each element in the `ARRAY`. Resource: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays