# BigQuery error ARRAY<STRUCT<gameType STRING, amount ARRAY<STRUCT<amount FLOAT64, type STRING>>>>

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

I have some tables on BigQuery that the schema looks like below.

[image]

[image]
When I execute the below query I got some exceptions

```
select * from `test.test.test_partitioned` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2020-03-01"  and account.final_balance_sum >1

Cannot access field final_balance_sum on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<account_name STRING, final_balance_sum FLOAT64>> at [16:141]
```

[image]

I have tried the solution from here, seems it doesn't work to me at all.

[Cannot access field in Big Query with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109817/cannot-access-field-in-big-query-with-type-arraystructhitnumber-int64-time-in/39110135)

Comment: can you share the schema of your table? seems like your table has nested fields.

Comment: Yes, it nested fields, I have attached my schemas on the ticket now

Comment: I don't see final_balance_sum to be part of account record column. Did you try running -  select * from `test.test.test_partitioned` WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2020-03-01"  and final_balance_sum >1

Comment: Yes, tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * EXCEPT(acc)
from `test.test.test_partitioned`,
UNNEST(account) acc
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2020-03-01"  
and acc.final_balance_sum >1
```